# Python3.4 PIP install error while building

Tags: python, pip

I'm having troubles installing python packages with PIP. I'm running on Windows 7, using pyzo IEP.
When typing `pip install <package>`, it starts running, downloading and copying files, but whenever it gets to the 'building' phase, it crashes, with several errors. Here is what I got when trying to install Biopython:

> running build_ext
>
> building 'Bio.cpairwise2' extension
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in
>
> File "C:\Windows\Temp\pip_build_ItayMNB5\Biopython\setup.py", line
>   480, in
>
> ```
> setup(**setup_args)
> ```
>
> File "C:\pyzo2014a\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
>
> ```
> dist.run_commands()
> ```
>
> File "C:\pyzo2014a\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
>
> ```
> self.run_command(cmd)
> ```
>
> File "C:\pyzo2014a\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
>
> ```
> cmd_obj.run()
> ```
>
> File "C:\Windows\Temp\pip_build_ItayMNB5\Biopython\setup.py", line
>   235, in run
>
> ```
> install.run(self)
> ```
>
> File "C:\pyzo2014a\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 554, in
>   run
>
> ```
> self.run_command('build')
> ```
>
> File "C:\pyzo2014a\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
>
> ```
> self.distribution.run_command(command)
> ```
>
> File "C:\pyzo2014a\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
>
> ```
> cmd_obj.run()
> ```
>
> File "C:\pyzo2014a\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 126, in run
>
> ```
> self.run_command(cmd_name)
> ```
>
> File "C:\pyzo2014a\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
>
> ```
> self.distribution.run_command(command)
> ```
>
> File "C:\pyzo2014a\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
>
> ```
> cmd_obj.run()
> ```
>
> File "C:\Windows\Temp\pip_build_ItayMNB5\Biopython\setup.py", line
>   252, in run
>
> ```
> build_ext.run(self)
> ```
>
> File "C:\pyzo2014a\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 348, in
>   run
>
> ```
> self.build_extensions()
> ```
>
> File "C:\pyzo2014a\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 457, in
>   build_extensions
>
> ```
> self.build_extension(ext)
> ```
>
> File "C:\pyzo2014a\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 512, in
>   build_extension
>
> ```
> depends=ext.depends)
> ```
>
> File "C:\pyzo2014a\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 460, in
>   compile
>
> ```
> self.initialize()
> ```
>
> File "C:\pyzo2014a\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 371, in
>   initialize
>
> ```
> vc_env = query_vcvarsall(VERSION, plat_spec)
> ```
>
> File "C:\pyzo2014a\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 287, in
>   query_vcvarsall
>
> ```
> raise ValueError(str(list(result.keys())))
> ```
>
> ValueError: ['path']

Similar stuff comes up when I try to install other packages.
I tried reinstalling python, but nothing changed. Any ideas what the problem might be?
Thanks!